# Can aws Kinesis steam be used as priority queue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to prioritize data to fetch first from the stream regardless of when it was put into the stream. For example, I am writing two types of data A and B into the stream; I want data of type A to always be ahead of type B even though type B was written into the stream first. (data is feeding on stream to AWS lambda for execution).
I couldn’t find any information regarding the priority on the AWS website. The only solution I could think of was to have two steams setup and vary the read limits on them.
If there is anything like priority queue/stream in Kinesis, please give me some info on it.

Thank you,
Jaydeep

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to do that with Kinesis. It's possible you could set `PartitionKey` or `ExplicitHashKey` to make some messages go to certain shards, where some shards are processed faster / more urgently. That's not quite the same, though.

[SQS doesn't support priority queues either, unfortunately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970289/how-to-implement-a-priority-queue-using-sqsamazon-simple-queue-service), but that SO thread has a few suggestions for alternatives.